# How can I put text above RadioButtonBar?

Tags: button

Is there a way to put text (e.g. a question) above a radio button box such as the one below, either

- in the main part of the box (area marked blue), or
- in the header (area marked red),
- or in both?

I couldn't find any way to do this under "Options" in the help for `RadioButtonBar`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've worked out the way to put text in the blue area. It's quite straightforward and requires giving another argument to `Column` rather than to `RadioButtonBar`:

```
Clear[a]; While[Not[StringQ[a]],
 a = DialogInput[{choice = {}},
 Column[{
 "\n Some text goes here \n",
 RadioButtonBar[Dynamic[choice], {"One", "Two", "Three"}],
 Button["Okay", If[choice =!= {}, DialogReturn[choice]]]
 }]]]
```

[image]